# How to correctly create, initialize and access to a static member of a class?

Tags: c++, c++11, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.x

I'm making a poker game and I have a class which contains a `std::map` to assign a value for every card on the poker deck referring to its name. I tried to put it as a component of another class as `static` member, since I have to assign a value every time a card is created, but for some reason when I try to access to it I get compiler error undefined symbol or duplicated symbol.

My partial solution have been declaring the class container as a global variable outside a class scope, but I know it's a bad practice , and if not there is anyway my doubt.

```
extern Baraja baraja;
```

For some reason when I declare this as `static` member or `static const` member, happens that I cannot access to the values of the `std::map` or I get compiler error `undefined symbol` or `duplicated symbol` so as I have searched in web documentations and cannot find a reason or solution I have this question.

How to correctly create, initialize and access to a static member of a class?

Answer (score 3):

I think this is duplicated.

```
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

enum class CardColor {Heart};

struct Card
{
    CardColor color;
    int value;
};

class Game
{
private:
    static std::unordered_map<std::string, Card> deck;
public:
    Game(){}
};
```

In your .cpp file

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, Card> Game::deck = std::unordered_map<std::string, Card>
{
    std::pair<std::string,Card>{"HeartSeven",{ CardColor::Heart,7}},
    std::pair<std::string,Card>{"HeartEight",{ CardColor::Heart,8}}
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there a document or book you can reccomend to know this better?

Comment: @IbrahimCS [this article](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static) provides a relatively technical description of what you've encountered. If you're looking for a more guided explanation, searching for 'static data member initialization' (i.e. what this answer demonstrates) will yield many more examples.